# What's the probability of exactly one green ball and one red ball drawn?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Suppose you have a bag of 6 balls and you will select two balls from the bag. There are 3 green balls, 2 red balls, and 1 yellow ball. If you select one ball at a time, without replacement, what is the probability that exactly one green ball and exactly one red ball is drawn?

My question is, do I have the event right here?

Sample space : $|S|=$$6\choose 2$ = 15

The event : $|E|=$$6\choose 5$ = 6

Therefore $p(E)$ = $\frac{6}{15}$ = 0.4 or 40%

Comment: I don´t know from where  you  have got $\binom{6}5$. I would calculate $\binom{3}1\cdot \binom{2}1\cdot \binom{1}0$

Comment: The answer is correct, but I agree with @callculus: $\binom65$ is a mystery to me.

Comment: I used that because out of 6 possible balls, 5 of them are either green or red, but now that I think about it, after you choose one, then that only leaves 5 balls to choose from. So I guess $6\choose 5$ wouldn't make much sense.